# Install4j created .app file for MAC is not showing any running instance warning message while uninstalling that application or deleting .app file.

Tags: install4j

I am uninstalling/deleting .app file on the MAC which is Install4J created.But it is not giving any running instance of file message while doing so.
Same scenario happens while installing, as i have running instance of the application and when i am trying to install the application again on the same location, it should prompt me with the message that the application is already running and one can't install at the same location. But it is not giving any such message.
Could somebody suggest me if some configuration or changes need to be set while building the installer on install4j??

Comment: Have you tried adding a "Check for running processes" action before the "Install files" action?

Comment: In install4j it is giving the option "Check for running processes for Windows". But i am having this query for MAC machine. Is there way to do so on MAC machine??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for running processes on Mac OS X requires at least install4j 6. In install4j 5.x and earlier this feature is not supported.

---

Update 2015-07-10:

In addition there is a bug that running process checking for "single bundle installer" media file types is broken. This will be fixed in 6.0.4.

Comment: I have one more doubt that as the description of the added feature of "Check for running processes" in version 6.0.3 mentions only for Windows and MAC platform, so does it mean that it do not support the same feature for Linux?? 
And what is the related bug you are talking about for this feature that is broken??

Comment: Linux is not supported by this action. In the update I mentioned that it does not detect running launchers for a particular media file type on Mac OS X.

Comment: So, when will the 6.0.4 version of install4j be available??

Comment: Not able to get this 6.0.4 version of install4j. Still the latest install4j available is 6.0.3. Is the delivery for 6.0.4 has been delayed or what??

Comment: Yes, it has been delayed. Now it's available.